# How to generate IP relative addressing instructions with GCC

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

I wrote a small program to test GCC's options.

```
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    __asm__("movl %0,%%ecx\n"
            "jmp jmpsection\n"
            "inc %%ecx\n"
            "jmpsection: movl $1,%%eax\n"
            "movl $0,%%ebx\n"
            "int $0x80\n"::"a"(a):"ecx","ebx");
}
```

In order to keep var a equal to 1, skip the inc instruction.
I want to force GCC to generate the jmp instruction using IP relative addressing method.
I have searched the GCC manual to find a solution, but I feiled.
Thanks for replay.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC/X86, Problems with relative jumps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638775/gcc-x86-problems-with-relative-jumps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the x86, IP relative addressing is only possible in long mode (64 bit) and you seem to be writing 32 bit code.

**Edit:** Actually, in 32 bit mode it *is* possible to make jumps relative to the current IP and I think the compiler actually generates the correct code in your case. Let's take a look at the relevant part of the generated assembly:

```
00000000 <main>:
  ...
  13:   eb 01                   jmp    16 <jmpsection>
  15:   41                      inc    %ecx

00000016 <jmpsection>:
  16:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  ...
```

So, although it *looks* like the instruction at address 13 makes a direct jump to address 16, it actually *is* an IP relative jump. Take a look at the machine code:

```
eb 01
```

`eb` is the opcode for a short `jmp` with an 8-bit displacement. `01` is this displacement. The result of this instruction is a jump to `%eip + 0x01` and, as the IP points to the *next* instruction to be executed, this will jump to address 16.

Comment: I don't think so. [Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)  In this article, the writer wrote the shellcode using IP relative addressing. And from the Disassemble code in  shellcodeasm.c you can see that.

Comment: @Job Why it is a 8bits displacement?

Comment: And is it always a near call using displacement relative to next instruction? What if it uses a far call when address is given. In this case, we can't get the offset?

Answer (score 1):

When you use inline assembly in GCC the assembly code is just passed on directly to the assembler. GCCs command line options do not change your assembly code. You can verify that looking at the output (use the -S option). The compiler options only change the way GCC generates assembly from C Code.

So instead of your compilers manual you need to look at your [assemblers manual](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas/html_node/as_toc.html). In your case GAS will probably select the short PC relative coding for `jmp` without the need to specify any options.